# Functional completeness of two functions

Tags: boolean-algebra

Given 2 functions: $$f(x,y,z) = yz'+xy' $$$$ h(x,y,z)=y'+xz$$
Trying to check if f and g are functionally complete.$$$$
The solution of this problem is to substitute x in f with h. 
Why is this the way to solve this, I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question should be closed.

Comment: Suggested alternative?

Comment: math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @LeonHeller Since when Boolean algebra is not relevant in electronics design? The question could show a bit more effort, but it's not off-topic.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati A lot of mechanical engineering has relevance to practical electronics design too, but if the question were solely about mech eng I'd still think it was off topic.

Comment: Im studying EE. This question is part of an EE course.

Comment: Also this question falls under the boolean-logic tag. I believe it is a valid question.@LeonHeller

Comment: @NickJohnson Sorry, but I don't agree. 1st) mechanical engineering is not a topic commonly comprised in an Electronics Engineering curriculum, while Boolean algebra is. 2nd) By your argument any theoretical basis of electronics should be deemed off-topic here, but this contradicts the very statement of the [help center](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), where it is said that "the *theory* and simulation of electromagnetic forces" is on-topic. By extension, I consider on-topic the theoretical/mathematical basis of every field of electrical/electronics engineering.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Theoretical basis of electronics still explicitly concerns electronics. This question, as posed, is purely a boolean logic one.

Comment: @NickJohnson Sorry, but I still don't agree. By the same argument, any question about Maxwell's equations (for example) should be banned altogether.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati I agree that the boolean algebra is purely mathematical discipline, but the point is that it is most widely used by electronic engineering, not even mathematicians. Well, they use it as well, but in a quite different way and notation. So I guess there is no other place to go with this type of questions. Update: Sorry, I think I've addresed the wrong person..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yep! I was just about to ask you if there was a communication glitch :-)

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution of substituting \$h\$ in \$f \$ is giving the following expression $$ f(h(x,y,z),y,z) = yz'+h(x,y,z)y'= \\ = yz'+(y'+xz)y' = \\ = yz'+y'+xzy'\\ = yz'+y' = y'+z'=(yz)'=NAND(y, z) $$

While \$NAND\$ is a universal gate, i.e. functionally complete.

Comment: Hi, I understand the results, thats not the problem. The question is why substitution is a correct solution.

Comment: I have just shown you why it is the right solution. What don't you understand? Why NAND is universal?

Comment: UAND I understand, what I don't understand is why the substitution is made and what is the idea behind it. Thanks

Comment: @BenWell It's called "mathematical trick". Sometimes it is just done intuitively or based on experience, or randomly. Don't look for any specific explanation. The bottom line is that it is working.

Comment: Personally I would prove it in a different way. I would show that any one of three gates (AND, OR and NOT) can be implemented by either or both of these functions. Which looks easier to me..

Answer (score 0):

@EugeneSh showed you the math, I'll focus on the theory behind it.

First consider the definition of *functional completeness*. You can refer to this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness).

Excerpt:

> In logic, a functionally complete set of logical connectives or
>   Boolean operators is one which can be used to express all possible
>   truth tables by combining members of the set into a Boolean
>   expression.

Therefore you have the set \$\{f,h\}\$ of these ternary Boolean operators. To show that they are functionally complete @EugeneSh showed that they can be used to generate another Boolean operator (NAND) which is known to be functionally complete. Therefore, as per the definition, the set \$\{f,h\}\$ is functionally complete because it can be used to compute any truth table, since you can use those two operators to construct the NAND and the NAND to construct any truth table.

As @Eugene said, the proof is based on a "trick", i.e. an educated guess (based on experience, intuition, etc.).